# Nautilus in Gnome: How to create a bookmark?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 15.04

I'd like to create a bookmark of a folder like described here:

[How can you access a folder you want quickly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126446/how-can-you-access-a-folder-you-want-quickly/126451#126451)

However, there is **no menu-entry under Gnome**. This is where it should appear:

[image]

Comment: After re-reading your question I am not sure to understand, do you mean that this [section in red](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aoVzo.png) is missing for you ?

Comment: Hi @hg8 . It doesn't appear. The menu you posted is missing in Gnome (Numix template). Ctr-D isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you need to have at least one bookmark for the bookmark section to appear.

---

**For future reference :**

To bookmark a folder, select on the menu bar : **Bookmarks** > **Bookmark this location**, or use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut.

[image: Bookmarl]